# ui:repeat does not detect error messages in #{facesContext.messageList}

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, message, myfaces, uirepeat

I am using JSF 2.2 (Myfaces 2.2.9).

I want to iterate over messages in JSF to display the errors, and I have some trouble with the ui:repeat element.

My .xhtml page :

```
    message size = #{facesContext.messageList.size()}
    <br />
    <ui:repeat var="msg" value="#{facesContext.messageList}">
        #{msg.detail}
    </ui:repeat>
```

When my form is submitted, it calls a function of my backing bean.
In that function, I add an "INFO" global message and I get it when my .xhtml page is displayed :

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "info message", "info message"));
```

Then it displays :

```
message size = 1  
info message
```

But if I change the severity to SEVERITY_ERROR :

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "info message", "info message"));
```

then the view does not display any message, even though the size is not empty:

```
message size = 1
```

Same if I just add the error message after the info message :

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "info message", "info message"));  
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "error message", "error message"));  

message size = 2
```

It seems adding a message of severity different from INFO is screwing things.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is driving me crazy...

I checked many answers talking about the life cycle (BalusC answers), and what I understood is that ui:repeat is executed as render time. So it should work.

Comment: Why are you not using `<h:messages />`?

Comment: Because I want to format the error messages in a certain way...

Comment: You can do this with '<h:messages />' by specifying a `rendererType` and implementing a custom renderer which extends `MessagesRenderer`.

Comment: @unwichtich : Thanks  but I would prefer to understand what did I do wrong, because it should work the way I tried. I saw people doing quite the same thing, and I really don't see what I did wrong.